# the if statement help{noob}

Tags: c#, if-statement

first of all i just want to say that i am a noob when it comes to c# programming., also i think this is an if statement situation, i could be wrong

I have google my query and cannot fing an answer :/

so heres my question:
Lets say i have the equation x + y = z
(both x and y are numbers that are entered in at the console)
now if i enter 5 for x and y in the console i will get

5 + 5 =10
However if i want it to say something else if 'z' goes above 10,

how do i go about it?

eg. 6 + 6 = 12
Here 12 is greater 10, an so i want it to say
    6 + 6 = "TRust to large"

It might be hard to understand what im looking for here, ino its very badly written!

Comment: Yes, as a basic level, this could be an `if` statement.

Comment: did you try doing a search on google of "C# if statement"?

Comment: yes but i could not understand what they were saying..i need it to be in basic english, i only started programing last week

Comment: "I have google my query and cannot fing an answer :/" ok, anybody bring a bazooka and kill me, I don't want to live anymore,

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're after something as simple as:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", x, y, x + y);
if (x + y > 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("TRust too large");
}
```

An `if` statement is basically just a condition, with some code to execute if that condition is met - and potentially another piece of code to execute if the condition *isn't* met (via `else`).

Note that the above code will *always* print the first line. As an example of an `if` / `else` you could make it *only* print the result if it's in range:

```
if (x + y > 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("TRust too large");
}
else
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", x, y, x + y);
}
```

Or if you find it more readable to put the "happy path" first:

```
if (x + y <= 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", x, y, x + y);
}
else
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("TRust too large");
}
```

Or having extracted the common code, to avoid problems if you ever change the formula:

```
int sum = x + y;
if (sum <= 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", x, y, sum);
}
else
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("TRust too large");
}
```

Comment: You missed else statement,

Comment: @FaisalHafeez: What do you mean? I mentioned it, but there's no indication that it's required. Will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (x + y <= 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", x, y, x+y);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = TRust too large", x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok lets see like this.
you're getting a result in `z` the make **z** as **comparing** to another things like whatever you want it may be a `variable` or a `number(aka integer)`.

comparing means that `>`(Greater than), `<`(less than), `!=`(not equal to ), `==`(equals to, it check whether two things are equal or not ? ), you can also use `<=` , `>=` ,

```
if(z>10){
// print something to console here
}else{
// the else things will go here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like:

```
var x = 5; //change by your component or readline
var y = 5; //change by your component or readline
if(x+y <= 10)
{
 var z = x + y;
}
else
 Console.WriteLine("TRust too large");
```